# Content type selector for custom forms

Tags: content-type, display-form, forms-7

I am working on a list where we have three content types (Client self-service, Service, and Intake). When a user comes to the site the default content type is Client self-service (Item1). After they complete the form, a person from my team needs to be able to open Item1 and "flip" the content type to Service and complete the added fields. This is the same process to move to Intake.

I plan to use custom forms, so they look nice, BUT my issue is that when I do that the SharePoint Content Type selector is no longer displayed on the Edit form for each content type.
[image]

How do I get the content type selector to display similar to the OOTB Sharepoint like the image below while being able to customize my forms?
[image]